# How to deal with image quality in magento?

Tags: image, magento, image-processing, magento-1.6

I've noticed that on my website Many of the images are overoptimized and have artifacting (blurry edges). They look really bad.

So i've been looking into what how magento (1.6) handles those conversions but I don't know id it does.

So you can give a look here to get an idea: [HERE](http://dev.quantum-wireless.com/landairsea-2507-c-gps-charger.html)

It depends on your monitor. Mine is good (bad) in the sense that these things stand out pretty clearly. Other monitors are more forgiving. So I'm looking to figure out how to do a higher quality compression ratio without sacrificing too much bandwidth with big files.

Is that possible ? Its hosted on Amazon Web Services.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A method called `setQuality` has been implemented and can be used directly in templates.

For example:

`echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize(42, 50)->setQuality(95);`

Answer (score 3):

I've [found this tutorial](http://tutorialmagento.com/set-quality-magento-product-images) around Google. New method called setQuality has been implemented since Magento CE 1.4 and can be used directly in template files. For example if you want to improve the quality of product images in category view, open `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml and add ->setQuality(100)` in the end of img src as follows:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(122,180)->setQuality(100); ?>" alt="" />
```

Now we have good quality images in the product list.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

magento 1.7 http://www.magentopowered.com/increase-product-images-quality-on-magento/ check this. While uploading product images, magento compress images. find:

```
$functionParameters = array();
$functionParameters[] = $this->_imageHandler;
$functionParameters[] = $fileName;
```

add below line:

```
$functionParameters[] = 100;
```

find:

```
if (!is_null($this->quality()) && $this->_fileType == IMAGETYPE_JPEG)
```

comment:

```
// $functionParameters[] = $this->quality();
```

Comment: That's hacking core logic. A better way to do it is the way the top answer describes, to use the `setQuality` method when you grab the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the free magento extension [Mediarocks_RetinaImages](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/retina-product-images.html) and set the quality via configuration. You don't need to enable the retina images if you don't need to.

Answer (score -3):

There is a setting in the backend, in System->Catalog->Image CDN where you can choose the image Compression Rate : from 1 to 9 ... easy, but it had to find !

Comment: I am using 1.7 and can't find this option.

Comment: Has been removed in 1.7 apparently