# Why all images get blurred into magento after upload

Tags: image, magento, product

Is there any solution which does not blur the image. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384678/magento-resize-image-quality-dirty-white-background)

but no changes in my images after removing all the caches. I used also `setQuality()` for setting image to `99%` but images seems little blurry in their edges.

Share any working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution will work for you.

Take file /lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php and save it to 
/app/code/local/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php

Please find these lines to be at line 147.

// set quality param for JPG file type

```
if (!is_null($this-&gt;quality()) &amp;&amp; $this-&gt;_fileType == IMAGETYPE_JPEG)
{
  $functionParameters 

                [] = $this-&gt;quality();
}
```

Replace the above line with the following line.

// set quality param for JPG file type

```
if (!is_null($this-&gt;quality()) &amp;&amp; $this-&gt;_fileType == IMAGETYPE_JPEG)
 {
    $functionParameters[] = 90;
 }
```

After saving, flush your catalog image cache (from System -> Cache Management in the Magento backend) then refresh your store and see if that sorts out your problem.